# How to subset data based on another column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

There is a DataFrame df:

```
a  b
1  True
2  True
3  False
```

How do you make a subset of column a where column b is True?

output:

```
a 
1 
2
```

Comment: What does your code look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: `df[df.b]`.... seriously you could've googled this

Comment: if your column C is boolean you can do what @COLDSPEED recommend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and instead mask use column `b`:

...if need `Series` add `a`:

```
s = df.loc[df.b, 'a']
print (s)
0    1
1    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

...if need `DataFrame` (one column) add `a` in list:

```
df1 = df.loc[df.b, ['a']]
print (df1)
   a
0  1
1  2
```

And for all columns need `boolean indexing` only:

```
df1 = df[df.b]
print (df1)
   a     b
0  1  True
1  2  True
```

Also is possible use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
print (df.query('b')['a'])
0    1
1    2
Name: a, dtype: int64

print (df.query('b')[['a']])
   a
0  1
1  2

print (df.query('b'))
   a     b
0  1  True
1  2  True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get back the data frame, use:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df[df['b'] == True]['a'])
```

If you want to get the output a, use:

```
df1 = df[df['b'] == True]['a']
print (df1)
```